# Why does Li hate Mizuki?

Tags: cardcaptor-sakura

We know that Li is attracted to Yukito because of their magic alignments (Moon), and he blushes every time they meet.

From the moment Li meets Mizuki, he distrusts her, giving her lots of angry glares.

[image: mizuki]
[image: li]

But Mizuki is the bearer of the Moon Bell; why is Li not attracted to this magic, like he was with Yukito?

Sakura seems to be attracted equally to both characters, feeling "hanyan" around them both.

[image: hanyan]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there wasn't much of a revelation about why Syaoran acts that way in front of Miss Kaho Mizuki. Though for me, it would really make more sense if Syaoran would find himself attracted to her powers just like how he feels with Yukito. Nevertheless, Syaoran felt worried when Miss Mizuki is around, maybe, that's how Syaoran shows his alertness because of Mizuki-sensei's mysteriousness.

Comment: Yeah. He probably can't read if Mizuki is a friend or a rival so that's how he reacted towards her. I know Mizuki was intentionally sending moon powers signal to Cerberus for her to lure away Yue's alter-ego, Yukito. So it's still a mystery as to why Syaoran reacted differently the way he reacted with Yukito when it's the same moon power signal.

Comment: Perhaps he acts' strongly' to moon power, rather than positively